# WinRT How to save the Image of the ContactPicker IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

With the following code I can get a `IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType` representing the Thumbal of a contact

```
var contactPicker = new ContactPicker();
contactPicker.SelectionMode = ContactSelectionMode.Contacts;

var contact = await contactPicker.PickSingleContactAsync();
var thumb = await contact.GetThumbnailAsync();
```

But what is the best way to handle the `IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType`  to get a image instance and a imagefile ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just handle it as an ordinary `IRandomAccessStream` containing the image:

```
using (var stream = await contact.GetThumbnailAsync())
{
    BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
    BitmapFrame frame = await decoder.GetFrameAsync(0);

    var bitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)frame.PixelWidth, (int)frame.PixelHeight);
    stream.Seek(0);
    await bitmap.SetSourceAsync(stream);
}
```

From here on you can set the `WriteableBitmap` as asource to `Image` control or use it in any other way.

The `Seek` call is required because the stream is already read to get the image size so the position needs to be reset before reading the image itself.

Comment: Thanks for your reply seems like I was a little confused. I expected some special behavior. Thanks for clearing it :-)